# Mapping AppsKey+Up to enable Page up? (Autohotkey script)

Tags: autohotkey

I have tried all the following but i can't get it to work.

AppsKey & Up::PgUp

*AppsKey & Up::PgUp

AppsKeyUp::{PgUp}

Comment: On my sony vaio laptop, the page up and page down key is located on the up and down arrow key where i need to use Fn+Up to use Page up.
I want to add a shortcut to press rightclick context menu(Appskey) + Up arrow key to use the Page up key.

Comment: Yes, it is called AppsKey based on http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Comment: Win98/WinME, by any chance?

Comment: then the first syntax should work

Comment: keyboard deficiency / hardware limitation?

Comment: The first syntax did not work. It shows an error on that particular command line when i reload the script.
My keyboard do not have any deficiency or hw limitation.

Comment: What does the key history say?

Comment: >^Right::End ;RightCtrl+Right key to activate end
>^Left::Home ;RightCtrl+Left key to activate home
#N::Run Notepad ;Windows+n to activate notepad
All the above work fine but when i add AppsKey & Up::PgUp, it will show an error on that particular line.

Comment: Key history is the window you get when you double-click the script icon and `Ctrl+K`. Open the key history, press `AppsKey+Up` and refresh.

Comment: Try `Up & AppsKey`. `Up` has double meaning.

Comment: After i hold down Appskey in the script icon & Ctrl+K window, the right context menu came out so im unable to use AppsKey+Up. But after i close the right context menu, here is what it says in the key history window:4B  025   u 0.23 K               
A2  01D   u 0.51 LControl        
5D  15D   d 5.13 AppsKey         
26  148   d 0.30 Up              
26  148   u 0.28 Up              
5D  15D   u 0.14 AppsKey         
74  03F   d 8.36 F5

Comment: I tried Up & AppsKey::PgUp but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try using the up key key code. Not sure why it should be neccessary: `AppsKey && VK26::PgUp`

Comment: It still says error: invalid hotkey linetext:AppsKey && VK26::PgUp

Comment: Single ampersand - sorry for that.

Comment: It still didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
AppsKey & Up::Send, {PGUP}
```

Using hotkeys requires the use of send.